# Passing Params Behavior - Loses Params on Validation Failure / Refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently using the following method to create child associations (case_mains have a one_to_many relationship with notes).

Create Note link:

```
      <%= link_to 'New Note', new_note_path(:case_main_id => @case_main.id)%>
```

Note form:

```
  <%= form.hidden_field :case_main_id, :value => params[:case_main_id]%>
```

This mostly works, until I refresh the page after navigating to the note form, or more likely, fail a validation check on submit. Then the note form loses the case_main_id and gives me a "Case main can't be blank" error. Is there another method I should be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing, I suppose your form is a `form_for` or `form_with model: ...` tag, right?

If so, instead of doing this:

```
form.hidden_field :case_main_id, value: params[:case_main_id]
```

Do only this:

```
form.hidden_field :case_main_id
```

And on the `new` action set the case_main_id to the new note:

```
@note = Note.new(case_main_id: params[:case_main_id])
```

The problem with your current code is that the case_main_id is at `params[:note][:case_main_id]` after you submit the form.